# Simplify creation of references to object members for animation purposes?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write animation component for my game engine. Animation component has to modify (animate) values of any member of any game object. Problem is that members are usually value types, but animation component needs some kind of reference to them, to be able to change it.

First I thought about using **reflection**, but reflection is too slow. I read about other techniques in C# that may be able to help (**Pointers, Reflection.Emit, Expression trees, Dynamic Methods/Objects, delegates, lambda expressions, closures...**) But i don't know these things good enough, to be able to solve the problem.

*Animation component* would have methods that would be able to take and store a reference to random object's member and animate its value over time. Like this: `StartSomeAnimation(ref memberToAnimate)`
There would be other parameters (like animation length), but problem is with passing members. Reference to *memberToAnimate* would need to be stored (even if it is value type) so it can be updated by animation component every frame.

The closest I was able to get to the solution on my own is with lambda expressions and Action<> Func<> delegates (see example below). It is about 4x slower than directly changing members + some more garbage allocation. But I still can't make such simple method signature like in example above.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameItem g = new GameItem();
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized to:" + g.AnimatedField);
        g.StartSomeAnimation();
        // NOTE: in real application IntializeAnim method would create new animation object 
        // and add it to animation component that would call update method until 
        // animation is complete
        Console.WriteLine("Animation started:" + g.AnimatedField);
        Animation.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Animation update 1:" + g.AnimatedField);
        Animation.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Animation update 2:" + g.AnimatedField);
        Animation.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Animation update 3:" + g.AnimatedField);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class GameItem
{
    public int AnimatedField;// Could be any member of any GameItem class
    public void StartSomeAnimation()
    {
        // Question: can creation of getter and setter be moved inside the InitializeAnim method?
        Animation.IntializeAnim(
            () => AnimatedField, // return value of our member
            (x) => this.AnimatedField = x); // set value of our member
    }
}

class Animation // this is static dumb class just for simplicity's sake
{
    static Action<int> setter;
    static Func<int> getter;

    // works fine, but we have to write getters and setters each time we start an animation
    public static void IntializeAnim(Func<int> getter, Action<int> setter)
    {
        Animation.getter = getter;
        Animation.setter = setter;
    }

    // Ideally we would need to pass only a member like this,
    // but we get an ERROR: cannot use ref or out parameter inside an anonymous method lambda expression or query expression
    public static void IntializeAnim(ref int memberToAnimate)
    {
        Animation.getter = () => memberToAnimate;
        Animation.setter = (x) => memberToAnimate = x;
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        // just some quick test code that queries and changes the value of a member that we animate
        int currentValue = getter();
        if (currentValue == 0)
        {
            currentValue = 5;
            setter(currentValue);
        }
        else
            setter(currentValue + currentValue);
    }
}
```

EDIT: A more complete example added to hopefully make question a little clearer. Please focus on how closures are created with lambda expressions and not on game architecture. Currently for each member, we want to animate, two lambda expressions have to be written each time we start a new animation (*IntializeAnim* methods). **Can starting an animation be simplified?** Look at how `IntializeAnim` methods are called currently.

```
class Program
{
    static bool GameRunning = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create game items
        Lamp lamp = new Lamp();
        GameWolrd.AddGameItem(lamp);
        Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy();
        Enemy enemy2 = new Enemy();
        GameWolrd.AddGameItem(enemy1);
        GameWolrd.AddGameItem(enemy2);

        // simple game loop
        while (GameRunning)
        {
            GameWolrd.Update();
            AnimationComponent.Update();
        }
    }
}

static class GameWolrd
{
    static List<IGameItem> gameItems;
    public static void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameItems.Count; i++)
        {
            IGameItem gameItem = gameItems[i];
            gameItem.Update();
        }
    }
    public static void AddGameItem(IGameItem item)
    {
        gameItems.Add(item);
    }
}

static class AnimationComponent
{
    static List<IAnimation> animations;
    public static void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animations.Count; i++)
        {
            IAnimation animation = animations[i];
            if (animation.Parent == null ||
                animation.Parent.IsAlive == false ||
                animation.IsFinished)
            {// remove animations we don't need
                animations.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
            else // update animation
                animation.Update();
        }
    }
    public static void AddAnimation(IAnimation anim)
    {
        animations.Add(anim);
    }
}

interface IAnimation
{
    void Update();
    bool IsFinished;
    IGameItem Parent;
}

/// <summary>
/// Game items worry only about state changes. 
/// Nice state transitions/animations logics reside inside IAnimation objects
/// </summary>
interface IGameItem
{
    void Update();
    bool IsAlive;
}

#region GameItems
class Lamp : IGameItem
{
    public float Intensity;
    public float ConeRadius;
    public bool IsAlive;
    public Lamp()
    {
        // Question: can be creation of getter and setter moved 
        //           inside the InitializeAnim method?
        SineOscillation.IntializeAnim(
            () => Intensity, // getter
            (x) => this.Intensity = x,// setter
            parent: this,
            max: 1,
            min: 0.3f,
            speed: 2);
        // use same animation algorithm for different member
        SineOscillation.IntializeAnim(
            () => ConeRadius, // getter
            (x) => this.ConeRadius = x,// setter
            parent: this,
            max: 50,
            min: 20f,
            speed: 15); 
    }
    public void Update()
    {}
}
class Enemy : IGameItem
{
    public float EyesGlow;
    public float Health;
    public float Size;
    public bool IsAlive;
    public Enemy()
    {
        Health = 100f;
        Size = 20;
        // Question: can creation of getter and setter be moved 
        //           inside the InitializeAnim method?
        SineOscillation.IntializeAnim(
            () => EyesGlow, // getter
            (x) => this.EyesGlow = x,// setter
            parent: this,
            max: 1,
            min: 0.5f,
            speed: 0.5f);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (GotHitbyPlayer)
        {
            DecreaseValueAnimation.IntializeAnim(
            () => Health, // getter
            (x) => this.Health = x,// setter
            parent: this,
            amount: 10,
            speed: 1f);
            DecreaseValueAnimation.IntializeAnim(
            () => Size, // getter
            (x) => this.Size = x,// setter
            parent: this,
            amount: 1.5f,
            speed: 0.3f);
        }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Animations
public class SineOscillation : IAnimation
{
    Action<float> setter;
    Func<float> getter;
    float max;
    float min;
    float speed;
    bool IsFinished;
    IGameItem Parent;

    // works fine, but we have to write getters and setters each time we start an animation
    public static void IntializeAnim(Func<float> getter, Action<float> setter, IGameItem parent, float max, float min, float speed)
    {
        SineOscillation anim = new SineOscillation();
        anim.getter = getter;
        anim.setter = setter;
        anim.Parent = parent;
        anim.max = max;
        anim.min = min;
        anim.speed = speed;
        AnimationComponent.AddAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float calcualtedValue = // calculate value using sine formula (use getter if necessary)
        setter(calcualtedValue);
    }
}

public class DecreaseValueAnimation : IAnimation
{
    Action<float> setter;
    Func<float> getter;
    float startValue;
    float amount;
    float speed;
    bool IsFinished;
    IGameItem Parent;

    // works fine, but we have to write getters and setters each time we start an animation
    public static void IntializeAnim(Func<float> getter, Action<float> setter, IGameItem parent, float amount, float speed)
    {
        DecreaseValueAnimation anim = new DecreaseValueAnimation();
        anim.getter = getter;
        anim.setter = setter;
        anim.Parent = parent;
        anim.amount = amount;
        anim.startValue = getter();
        anim.speed = speed;
        AnimationComponent.AddAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float calcualtedValue = getter() - speed;
        if (calcualtedValue <= startValue - amount)
        {
            calcualtedValue = startValue - amount;
            this.IsFinished = true;
        }
        setter(calcualtedValue);
    }
} 
#endregion
```

Comment: I've never developed games on .NET, but do you have any reason to not use XNA or WPF frameworks?

Comment: I am using XNA framework. I created simplified example without any dependencies, because problem is not directly related to XNA but to C# language and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface:

```
interface IGameItem
{
    int AnimatedField { get; set; }
}

class GameItem : IGameItem
{
    public int AnimatedField { get; set; }
}

class Animation
{
    public IGameItem Item { get; set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Item.AnimatedField == 0)
        {
            Item.AnimatedField = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            Item.AnimatedField = Item.AnimatedField + Item.AnimatedField;
        }
    }
}
```

And running of your super-animation engine will look like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GameItem g = new GameItem() { AnimatedField = 1 };

        Animation a = new Animation() { Item = g };

        a.Update();

        Console.WriteLine(g.AnimatedField);

        a.Update();

        Console.WriteLine(g.AnimatedField);

        a.Update();

        Console.WriteLine(g.AnimatedField);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However, note that exposing public setters for everyone is not a good practice. Each class must be supplied with an interface which is fully used by it. Read about interface segregation principle and other SOLID principles.

**UPD:**

Another option is to make items to know how to animate themself:

```
interface IAnimatable
{
    void Animate();
}

class IntegerItem : IAnimatable
{
    int _n;
    public IntegerItem(int n)
    {
        _n = n;
    }

    public void Animate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_n);
    }
}

class AnimationSequencer
{
    public void Update(IAnimatable item)
    {
        item.Animate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Animation class doesn't know what members does the GameItem object have before animation is invoked, so it cannot store interface like this. AnimatedField is just one of many possibilities. There are many different GameItem classes, each with unique set of members.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't animate the thing you know nothing about. You can isolate animation engine from value-containers. For this purpose you need each value-container to implement an interface(s) and animation class should know how to work with this interface(s)

Comment: You only know the member type (animation object in my example can only animate integers). There are different animation classes for different types(int,vector,color..). They take in different functions for manipulating values. But I tried to keep it simple in the example. In full animation engine these animation object are created when IntializeAnim is called and added to animation component that calls update for each animation object until animation is complete. In example two clousures (getter and setter) are created so member can be animated even if you don't know beforehand what member.

Comment: It is impossible for each animation class to know all possible value-container interfaces (or at least there would be exponential amount of code duplication). Maybe a better example would help: We have AnimationEaseInOut class that creates ease-in-out transition of a float value. We can use instances of this class to change opacity and size of an player character, change health value of enemy object, change Y position of ball bouncing object etc

Comment: @to make items to know how to animate themself: this would make animation tightly coupled with main game. Each time an member would need to be animated it would need to be converted to IAnimatable class. And all game objects that interact with that member would need to be updated. Also same value types (like IntegerItem) need to do many different animations, so animation can not be coupled with IntegerItem objects (there are dozens different animations for integer type alone)

Comment: I have added a more complete example that may help understand the animation system. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Animation
{
    public static void Initialize(object element)
    {
        //// initialize code
    }

    public static void Update(object element)
    {
        //// update code
    }
}

public class GameItem : Animatable
{
    public GameItem(object memberToAnimate)
    {
        this.MemberToAnimate = memberToAnimate;
    }      
}

public class Animatable
{
    public object MemberToAnimate { get; set; }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Animation.Initialize(this.MemberToAnimate);
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        Animation.Update(this.MemberToAnimate);
    }
}
```

Thus the code will be:

```
var gameItem = new GameItem(yourObjectToAnimate);
gameItem.Initialize();
gameItem.Update();
```

Comment: This will not work as it allows only predefined members to animate for game item (also there are different game item classes with different members). Also I would like to achieve greater decoupling of animation engine from the game itself.